# How can I have 2 Widgets in a column, where 1 of them is a scrollable Column?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

So I have two widgets in a column, one is a `Container` (top widget) and the other is a `Column` (bottom widget that should be scrollable), but the `Column` isn't being viewed as scrollable as shown in the image below:

[image: Result snippet]

Here's the `Container` and `Column` in code:

```
<Widget>[
    topBar, // Container
    Container(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column( // Column in container
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "Test",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
            ),
            Text(
              "Test",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
            ),
            Text(
              "Test",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
            ),
            // Insert Other Text Widgets below            
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
  ]
```

Where `topBar` is:

```
Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
    child: Text(
      'Top Container',
      style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 25.0
      ),
    ),
);
```

I've tried using `ListView` as mentioned in similar questions, but it does the same thing.

I suspect that it's because it's trying to go beyond the parent container, which isn't scrollable but I don't know how to get past that.

---

**UPDATE**

Just to clarify, what I'm trying to do is have a ScrollView with a fixed top bar, I don't want the bar to scroll too.

On Android it's just a case of creating two layouts, one with a ScrollView inside. But I'm guessing Flutter does things differently, and I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Please clarify something. You have a Column inside a Column? Could you also please share what you would like to achieve?

Comment: @JoãoSoares - The top-most column is for the top container and the column below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wrap your second `Column` in an `Expanded` it will try to occupy as much space as possible and then the overflowing elements in that `Column` will scroll. This should fix your problem. Example:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: HomePage());
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget topBar = Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
      child: Text(
        'Top Container',
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25.0),
      ),
    );
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          topBar, // Container

          Expanded( // <- Add this

            child: Container(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  // Column in container
                  children: <Widget>[
                    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
                      Text(
                        "Test",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded. This is the error.

Comment: Hmm, is the 1st Column (the one highest in our hierarchy) inside any other widget that could impact its dimensions? I tried to run this code in a test app it gave no errors. I'll edit the answer to show you my entire test app.

Comment: Yeah, it's in a Builder widget, like so: `Builder( builder: (context) => Column(... `

Comment: I'll try it your way :)

Comment: That works :) ... The issue was that the outer Column was itself in a container, Got rid of it and it works with the `Expanded()` widget. Thank You!!!

Comment: Never understood how useful `Expanded()` is :)